# Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x88\\xB2\\xE4\\xB8...' for column 'welcome_msg' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, django

I got this problem when saved the object by Django.
I have checked my table CharSet, As the following picture.

[image]

I dont know why this happen, Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: How did you save the object?...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I save the object by Admin Server, The code is generated by Django Admin